# Small PHP Viewer/Controller template

Tags: php, library

I have written a small template Viewer/Controller esque library that I would like some critiques on.

The library is [located here](https://github.com/maniator/SmallFry/tree/f957f3609c1f108c8cd3b79e4d47a57740e85b42)

If you are looking for where to start, check out `App.php` and `AppController.php` in the `classes` folder

I would really love to hear your critiques on:

- Code quality
- Code clarity
- How to improve
- Anything else that needs clarification expansion etc
- I have also heard that my static methods (like my `get` and `set` methods in `App`) should be replaced with something more *dynamic*, How would I go about doing that?

I'm more interested in what I'm doing wrong than right.

Any opinions on the actual usefulness of the library are welcome.

[App.php](https://github.com/maniator/SmallFry/blob/f957f3609c1f108c8cd3b79e4d47a57740e85b42/classes/App.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * Description of App
 *
 * @author nlubin
 */
class App {
    /**
     * Holds all of the app variables
     * @var array
     */
    private static $app_vars = array();
    /**
     * Will be an App object
     * @var App
     */
    private static $app = null;

    /**
     * Get a single app_vars variable
     * @param string $v
     * @return mixed 
     */
    public static function get($v){
        return isset(self::$app_vars[$v])?self::$app_vars[$v]:false;
    }

    /**
     * Get all app_vars variables
     * @return array app_vars
     */
    public static function getAll(){
        return self::$app_vars;
    }

    /**
     * Set an app_vars variable
     * 
     * @param string $v
     * @param mixed $va
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function set($v, $va){
        if(self::$app == null){ //create App on first set. if not, the app does not exist
            self::$app = new self();
        }
        return self::$app_vars[$v] = $va;
    }

    /**
     * Clean up the app_vars variable
     */
    public static function clean(){
        self::$app_vars = array();
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_connection = Database::getConnection();
    }

    private function render_template(){
        $rPath = $this->read_path();
        foreach($rPath as $key=>$value){
            $$key = $value;
        }
        unset($rPath);

        ob_start();

        App::set('page_title',App::get('DEFAULT_TITLE'));
        App::set('template',App::get('DEFAULT_TEMPLATE'));
        App::set('page',$page);

        //LOGIN
        if(!isset($_SESSION['LOGIN']) || $_SESSION['LOGIN'] == false){
            Login::check_login();
        }
        else {
            $modFolders = array('images', 'js', 'css');

            //load controller
            if(strlen($controller) == 0) $controller = App::get('DEFAULT_CONTROLLER');

            if(count(array_intersect($path_info, $modFolders)) == 0){ //load it only if it is not in one of those folders
                $controllerName = "{$controller}Controller";
                $app_controller = $this->create_controller($controllerName, $args); 
            }
            else {  //fake mod-rewrite
                $this->rewrite($path_info);
            }
        }

        $main = ob_get_clean();
        App::set('main', $main);
        //LOAD VIEW
        ob_start();
        $this->load_view($app_controller, 0);
        //END LOAD VIEW

        //LOAD TEMPLATE
        $main = ob_get_clean();
        App::set('main', $main);
        $this->load_template($app_controller, $app_controller->get('jQuery'));
        //END LOAD TEMPLATE
    }


    private function read_path(){
        $path = isset($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"])?$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]:'/'.App::get('DEFAULT_CONTROLLER');
        $path_info = explode("/",$path);
        $page = (isset($path_info[2]) && strlen($path_info[2]) > 0)?$path_info[2]:'index';
        list($page, $temp) = explode('.', $page) + array('index', null);
        $args = array_slice($path_info, 3);
        $controller = isset($path_info[1])?$path_info[1]:App::get('DEFAULT_CONTROLLER');
        return array(
            'path_info'=>$path_info,
            'page'=>$page,
            'args'=>$args,
            'controller'=>$controller
        );
    }

    private function create_controller($controllerName, $args = array()){
        if (class_exists($controllerName)) {  
            $app_controller  = new $controllerName(); 
        } else {
            //show nothing 
            header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
            exit;
        }
        echo $app_controller->display_page($args);
        return $app_controller;
    }

    private function load_template($controllerName, $jQuery = null){

        $page_title = $controllerName->get('title')?$controllerName->get('title'):App::get('DEFAULT_TITLE');
        //display output
        $cwd = dirname(__FILE__);
        $template_file = $cwd.'/../view/'.App::get('template').'.stp';
        if(is_file($template_file)){
            include $template_file;
        }
        else {
            include $cwd.'/../view/missingfile.stp'; //no such file error
        }
    }

    private function load_view($controllerName, $saveIndex){

        //Bring the variables to the global scope
        $vars = $controllerName->getAll();
        foreach($vars as $key=>$variable){
            $$key = $variable;
        }
        $cwd = dirname(__FILE__);
        if(App::get('view')){
            $template_file = $cwd.'/../view/'.App::get('view').'/'.App::get('method').'.stp';
            if(is_file($template_file)){
                include $template_file;
            }
            else {
                include $cwd.'/../view/missingview.stp'; //no such view error
            }
        }
        else {
            App::set('template', 'blank');
            include $cwd.'/../view/missingfunction.stp'; //no such function error
        }
    }


    private function rewrite($path_info){
        $rewrite = $path_info[count($path_info) - 2];
        $file_name = $path_info[count($path_info) - 1];

        $file = WEBROOT.$rewrite."/".$file_name;
//                echo $file; 
        header('Location: '.$file);
        exit;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->render_template();
    }
}

?>
```

[AppController.php](https://github.com/maniator/SmallFry/blob/f957f3609c1f108c8cd3b79e4d47a57740e85b42/classes/AppController.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Description of AppController
 *
 * @author nlubin
 */
class AppController {

    /**
     *
     * @var mySQL
     */
    protected $_mysql;
    protected $_page_on,
            $_allowed_pages = array(),
            $_not_allowed_pages = array(
                '__construct', 'get', 'set', 
                'getAll', 'display_page', 'error_page',
                'include_jQuery', 'include_js', '_setHelpers',
                '_validate_posts', '_doValidate', '_make_error'
            );
    protected $app_vars = array();
    var $name = __CLASS__;
    var $helpers = array();
    var $validate = array();
    var $posts = array();
    protected $validator;

    public function __construct()   {
        $this->_mysql = Database::getConnection();
        $this->_page_on = App::get('page');
        App::set('view', strtolower($this->name));
        $this->_allowed_pages = get_class_methods($this);
        $this->set('jQuery', $this->include_jQuery());
        $this->setHelpers();
        $this->validator = new FormValidator();
        $this->_validate_posts();
        $this->posts = (object) $this->posts;
        if(!isset($_SESSION[App::get('APP_NAME')][strtolower($this->name)])){
            $_SESSION[App::get('APP_NAME')][strtolower($this->name)] = array();
        }
        return;
    }

    public function init(){

    }

    public function get($v){
        return isset($this->app_vars[$v])?$this->app_vars[$v]:false;
    }

    protected function set($v, $va){
        return $this->app_vars[$v] = $va;
    }

    public function getAll(){
        return $this->app_vars;
    }
    /**
     * Show the current page in the browser
     * @return string 
     */
    public function display_page($args)  {
        App::set('method', $this->_page_on);
        $private_fn = (strpos($this->_page_on, '__') === 0);
        if(in_array($this->_page_on, $this->_allowed_pages) 
                && !in_array($this->_page_on, $this->_not_allowed_pages)
                        && !$private_fn)    {  
            $home = $this->include_jQuery();
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->_page_on), $args);
        }
        else    {
            if(App::get('view') == strtolower(__CLASS__) || $private_fn ||
                    in_array($this->_page_on, $this->_not_allowed_pages)){
                header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
            }
            else {
                App::set('method', '../missingfunction'); //don't even allow trying the page
                return($this->error_page(App::get('view')."/{$this->_page_on} does not exist."));
            }
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    function index()    {}

    /**
     *
     * @param string $msg
     * @return string 
     */
    protected function error_page($msg = null)    {
        $err = '<span class="error">%s</span>';
        return sprintf($err, $msg);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    protected function include_jQuery(){
        $ret = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>'.PHP_EOL;
        $ret .= '        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>'.PHP_EOL;
        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string $src
     * @return string 
     */
    protected function include_js($src){
        $script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/%s.js"></script>'.PHP_EOL;
        return sprintf($script, $src);
    }

    protected function setHelpers(){
        $helpers = array();
        foreach($this->helpers as $helper){
            $help = "{$helper}Helper";
            $this->$helper = new $help();
            $helpers[$helper] = $this->$helper;
        }
        self::set('helpers', (object) $helpers);
    }

    protected function logout(){
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: '.WEBROOT.'index.php');
        exit;
    }

    protected function _validate_posts(){
        foreach($this->validate as $field => $rules){
            foreach($rules as $validate=>$message){
                $this->validator->addValidation($field, $validate, $message);
            }
        }
        $this->_doValidate();
    }

    protected function _doValidate(){
        if(!(!isset($_POST) || count($_POST) == 0)){
            //some form was submitted
            if(!$this->validator->ValidateForm()){
                $error = '';
                $error_hash = $this->validator->GetErrors();
                foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
                {
                  $error .= "$inp_err<br/>\n";
                }
                $this->_make_error($error);                
            }

            foreach($_POST as $key=>$post){
                $this->posts[$key] = $post;
            }
        }
    }

    function __get($var_name){
//        echo $var_name."<br>";
        if(isset($this->posts->$var_name)){
            return $this->posts->$var_name;
        }
        else{
            ?><div class="errors"><?php
               echo "$var_name is not set<br/>\n";
            ?></div><?php
            exit;
        }
    }

    function __call($name, $arguments){
        if($name == 'mysql'){
            return (strlen($this->$arguments[0])==0?"NULL":"'{$this->$arguments[0]}'");
        }
    }

    function _make_error($str){
        ?><div class="errors"><?php
        echo $str;
        ?></div><?php
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've spent about 20 minutes reading your code and I've identified several issues.

### Relative paths

```
private function load_template($controllerName, $jQuery = null){
    $page_title = $controllerName->get('title') ? $controllerName->get('title') : App::get('DEFAULT_TITLE');

    //display output
    $cwd = dirname(__FILE__);
    $template_file = $cwd.'/../view/'.App::get('template').'.stp';
    if(is_file($template_file)){
        include $template_file;
    }
    else {
        include $cwd.'/../view/missingfile.stp'; //no such file error
    }
}
```

What happens if at a later point you decide to change your directory structure? Instead of using `dirname(__FILE__)` you could just pass that base directory as a function parameter.

### Function names inconsistencies

You prefix *some* private / protected variables and functions with an underscore:

```
protected $_mysql;
```

Two points:

1. Either do it for every private / protected variable and function or don't do it at all
2. Don't do it at all

Some justification on the second point:

- Every decent IDE out there allows for sorting of variables and functions based on their visibillity / scope. Eclipse goes a step further and uses green for public, and red for private / public in the Outline view, so everything is easily identifiable.
- In PHP functions that are prefixed with an underscore might be mistaken for magic methods (which are prefixed by two underscores).

Note that while almost all php IDEs will treat:

```
function foo()
```

as:

```
public function foo()
```

you could help the IDE by adding the public keyword. That's also a readibillity point and a PHP4 style (`function foo()`) vs PHP5 style (`public function foo()`).

### Inline HTML

```
protected function error_page($msg = null)    {
    $err = '<span class="error">%s</span>';
    return sprintf($err, $msg);
}

protected function include_jQuery(){
    $ret = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>'.PHP_EOL;
    $ret .= '        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>'.PHP_EOL;
    return $ret;
}

function __get($var_name){
    // echo $var_name."<br>";
    if(isset($this->posts->$var_name)){
        return $this->posts->$var_name;
    }
    else{
        ?><div class="errors"><?php
           echo "$var_name is not set<br/>\n";
        ?></div><?php
        exit;
    }
}
```

Don't do that, you **must** [separate presentation from logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html).

### Sessions

In AppController.php you utilize sessions:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION[App::get('APP_NAME')][strtolower($this->name)])){
    $_SESSION[App::get('APP_NAME')][strtolower($this->name)] = array();
}
```

But you don't have `session_start()` at the beginning of the script. Granted, you probably start the session in the caller script, but that means that your class will throw notices (`$_SESSION` array not initialized) if called from anywhere where `session_start()` hasn't been called. You can do something like:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION) ) session_start();
```

at the top of each script that uses sessions.

### Comments

You have some phpDoc comments, you need one for *every* function. But please note that I've been [accused](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/critique-request-php-cookie-library/2727#2727) of overcommenting :)

### PHP4 style class members

You are using some PHP4 style class members:

```
var $name = __CLASS__;
var $helpers = array();
var $validate = array();
var $posts = array();
```

You should be using PHP5 access control (public / private / protected) members everywhere.

### Ternary operator readability

This:

```
return isset(self::$app_vars[$v])?self::$app_vars[$v]:false;
```

is not very readable. Consider something like:

```
return
    isset(self::$app_vars[$v])
    ? self::$app_vars[$v]
    : false;
```

or at least something like this:

```
return isset(self::$app_vars[$v]) ? self::$app_vars[$v] : false;
```

Similarly, please add spaces before and after concatenation points:

```
$cwd.'/../view/'.App::get('template').'.stp'; // somewhat unreadable
$cwd . '/../view/'.App::get('template') . '.stp'; // friendlier to the eyes
```

### Minor stuff

```
private function load_template($controllerName, $jQuery = null) {}
```

You don't utilize the `$jQuery` variable in the function. Is your code complete? If not, you shouldn't have posted it up for review.

```
function __get($var_name){
    // echo $var_name."<br>";
    if(isset($this->posts->$var_name)){
        return $this->posts->$var_name;
    }
    else{
        ?><div class="errors"><?php
           echo "$var_name is not set<br/>\n";
        ?></div><?php
        exit;
    }
}
```

`else` is not needed (as `if block` returns, which means that execution of the function stops there):

```
function __get($var_name){
    // echo $var_name."<br>";
    if(isset($this->posts->$var_name)){
        return $this->posts->$var_name;
    }

    ?><div class="errors"><?php
       echo "$var_name is not set<br/>\n";
    ?></div><?php
    exit;        
}
```

Here:

```
private function create_controller($controllerName, $args = array()){
    if (class_exists($controllerName)) {
```

You treat `$controllerName` as a parameter that holds a class name, but in the very next function:

```
private function load_template($controllerName, $jQuery = null){
    $page_title = $controllerName->get('title')?$controllerName->get('title'):App::get('DEFAULT_TITLE');
```

you also have a `$controllerName` parameter that holds an object. Rename the second one to `$controller`.

### In conclusion

Your code has a lot of minor inconsistencies, several readabillity issues, a few major problems (especially the html thingy) and it's clearly still a work in progress (especially AppController.php). You need to try and at least rewrite it in a more consistent matter.

PS. You should remove `?>` from the end of every class script, as leo [suggests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/small-php-viewer-controller-template/5277#5277).

Comment: Wow. How thorough! look at this related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676515/should-i-remove-static-function-from-my-code

Comment: I have updated some of my library ^_^

Comment: [see my updated code](https://github.com/maniator/SmallFry/tree/5e1d2a3d1c2f14aeec0feaf8b0def5baa3ec8508) do you think I should make a new question related to it?

Comment: I just hope it doesnt get closed as a duplicate (I am fixing the underscore issue in my update coming soon, switching to all camelCase for the most part)

Comment: @Neal I don't think it would be a duplicate, you are not just copy pasting the same code, you've done a fair share of modifications. The discussion on what [constitutes a dupe in Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-do-we-define-duplicate-questions) is still open, so I can't really say for sure... But go for it, either way.

Comment: I have a question of how I can fix the `Relative paths`. Basically, how can I do it with my new code?

Comment: @Yanniss [Here is a chat link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2288204#2288204)

Comment: Here is my new question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/7531/3163

Comment: Still no use to my bounty on my new question hehe

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks acutally great, and it has also good PHP-Doc, but I think the comments inside the methods are a bit confusing, because they have always a different writing style (sometimes uppercase, sometimes lowercase, sometimes sentences sometimes just simple words etc.), so you should cleanup them and set a convention how you document these points in the code.

Also you should be a bit carefully with the foreach loop in `load_view`, because there you set `$$key = $variable;`. If you know what you are setting to the controller, this isn't anything bad, but what is if you try to set `$this`? I didn't try it, but it would actually generate an error, so I would recommend you just to create an array of reserved variables, which will be checked before loading the view. There you should also add the `$cwd` and the `$template_file`, perhaps there are more vars like these.

Also something I actually see in your code, what is just a bit of coding convention, is the closing PHP tag at the end of the file (`?>`). Of course I see many developers using that right now, but I recommend you to leave that away, you could instead just add a comment like `/* End of File */`. The problem is, if you have a space after the closing PHP Tag and you try to modify the header later, it won't work, you'll just get errors.

And the replacement of your `get` and `set` methods could be done with [PHP magic methods.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). You should use `__get($var)` and `__set($var)` than you could access them like normal object properties. E.g. `$this->newTemplateVar = "Hello World!";`.

I hope my post helps you; if not, just say it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with yannis. But 1 last thing.

Constructors are simply supposed to assign values to properties. Your constructor seems to do a lot more than that. Switch it up to accept a database connection. Remember statics are evil cause they make testing difficult.

```
$Settings   = new FileSettings(new File('Config.php'));
$MFactory   = new ModelFactory;
$TFactory   = new TemplateFactory($Settings['UI']['Template']);

$Database   = $MFactory->createDB($Settings['DB']['Driver'], ....);
$Request    = $MFactory->createRequest($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $_GET, $_POST);
$View       = $TFactory->createView($Request->getView());

$Controller = new Controller($Database, $TFactory, $MFactory);
$Action     = $Request->getAction()?: 'index';

if (is_callable(array($Controller, $Action))) {
    call_user_function(array($Controller, $Action));
}

else $Controller->error($Request);
```