# Cookie Management Class

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes, recursion, php5

I wrote this class to make cookie management easier.

I know it makes use of `serialize()`, but I have no intention of storing very much data in the cookie, and it seemed a cleaner solution than, say, the JSON functions (like, even if a class implements the `JSONSerializable` interface, it doesn't retain the class name by default, etc.). `serialize()` seemed more robust, although if there's a way to compress the output without it losing its integrity, please share. Probably the worst pitfall is that, if the cookie is messed with, `unserialize()` will trigger a notice and who knows what else -- but I don't feel I need to cater to the user experience of users who mess with cookies. (Although if the cookie is maxed out at a number of bytes, like 4,096, and it truncates, that could be an issue....)

I am in the process of writing a class to put on top of this one for managing user sessions implementing [Charles Miller's solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/critique-request-php-cookie-library).

I decided against implementing exceptions because it was simple enough to just return constants.

```
<?php
/**
 * Cookie.class.php, the Cookie class
 *
 * Contains a class for making cookies easier to manage via PHP
 * @author Miller <wyattstorch42 at outlook dot com>
 * @version 1.0
 * @package Miller
 * @subpackage Utils
 */

namespace Miller\Utils;

if (!function_exists('array_copy')) {
    /**
     * array_copy Properly and recursively clones an array
     * @param array $source The original array
     * @return array The clone
     */
    function array_copy ($source) {
        $return = array ();
        $keys = array_keys($source);
        $values = array_values($source);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); ++$i) {
            if (is_object($values[$i])) {
                $return[$keys[$i]] = clone $values[$i];
            }
            else if (is_array($values[$i])) {
                $return[$keys[$i]] = array_copy($values[$i]);
            }
            else {
                $return[$keys[$i]] = $values[$i];
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}

/**
 * A class for making cookies easier to manage via PHP
 * @package Miller\Utils
 */
class Cookie {
    /**
     * Class constants
     * SESSION, EXPIRE, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, and YEAR are used to define the life of the cookie
     * ERROR_HEADERS_SENT, ERROR_SET_COOKIE, and ERROR_NONE are possible return values for the sent() method.
     */
    const
        SESSION = 0,
        EXPIRE = -3600,
        DAY = 86400,
        WEEK = 604800,
        MONTH = 2592000,
        YEAR = 31536000,
        ERROR_HEADERS_SENT = -1,
        ERROR_SET_COOKIE = -2,
        ERROR_NONE = 1;

    protected
        /**
         * Holds the name of the cookie
         * @var string
         */
        $name,
        /**
         * Holds the expiration timestamp of the cookie
         * @var integer
         */
        $expiry,
        /**
         * Holds the path of the cookie
         * @var string
         */
        $path,
        /**
         * Holds the domain of the cookie
         * @var string
         */
        $domain,
        /**
         * A flag that sets the secure option for the cookie
         * @var boolean
         */
        $secure,
        /**
         * A flag that sets the httponly option for the cookie
         * @var boolean
         */
        $httponly,
        /**
         * An array that holds the current unserialized properties stored in the cookie
         * @var array
         */
        $properties,
        /**
         * An array that holds the properties that will be stored and serialzed in the cookie on send()
         * @var string
         */
        $internalProperties;

    public function __construct ($name, $expiry = self::WEEK, $path = '', $domain = '', $secure = null, $httponly = false) {
        /**
         * Constructor
         * @param string $name The name of the cookie
         * @param null|integer|string $expiry The expiration timestamp of the cookie (if null, sets a session cookie; if string, converts using strtotime())
         * @param string $path The path of the cookie
         * @param string $domain The domain of the cookie
         * @param null|boolean $secure The flag that sets the secure option for the cookie (if null, sets to true if $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is set, false otherwise)
         * @param boolean $httponly The flag that sets the httponly option for the cookie
         */
        $this->name = (string) $name;

        if ($expiry === self::SESSION) {
            $this->expiry = $expiry;
        }
        else if (is_numeric($expiry)) {
            $this->expiry = time()+$expiry;
        }
        else {
            $this->expiry = strtotime($expiry);
        }

        $this->path = (string) $path;
        $this->domain = (string) $domain;
        $this->secure = $secure === null ? isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] : (bool) $secure;
        $this->httponly = (bool) $httponly;

        $this->properties = array ();
        $this->internalProperties = array ();
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->name])) {
            $properties = unserialize($_COOKIE[$this->name]);
            $this->internalProperties = array_copy($properties);
            $this->properties = array_copy($properties);
        }
    }

    public function exists () {
        /**
         * Checks if the cookie was sent from the last browser request
         * @return bool True if the cookie is set, false otherwise
         */
        return (bool) $this->properties;
    }

    public function __isset ($property) {
        /**
         * Checks if the given property is set on the cookie
         * @param string $property The property key
         * @return bool True if the property is set, false otherwise
         */
        return isset($this->properties[$property]);
    }

    public function __get ($property) {
        /**
         * Returns the value of the given property on the cookie
         * @param string $property The property key
         * @return bool The value of the property if it is set, null otherwise (use __isset() to differentiate a null value from an undefined value)
         */
        return $this->__isset($property) ? $this->properties[$property] : null;
    }

    public function __set ($property, $value) {
        /**
         * Sets or overrides the given property (will not be accessible until the cookie is sent)
         * @param string $property The property key
         * @param mixed $value The value
         * @return void
         */
        $this->internalProperties[$property] = $value;
    }

public function __unset ($property) {
    /**
     * Unsets the given property (will not be accessible until the cookie is sent)
     * @param string $property The property key
     * @return void
     */
    if (isset($this->internalProperties[$property])) {
        unset($this->internalProperties[$property]);
    }
}

    public function send () {
        /**
         * Serializes the properties and sends the cookie to the browser. On success, updates the values of the properties.
         * @return integer ERROR_HEADERS_SENT if the headers have already been sent, ERROR_SET_COOKIE if the setcookie() function failed, or ERROR_NONE on success
         */
        if (headers_sent()) {
            return self::ERROR_HEADERS_SENT;
        }

        $value = $this->expiry === self::SESSION ? false : serialize($this->internalProperties);
        if (setcookie($this->name, $value, $this->expiry, $this->path, $this->domain, $this->secure, $this->httponly)) {
            $this->properties = array_copy($this->internalProperties);
            return self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return self::ERROR_SET_COOKIE;
    }
}
?>
```

Example usage:

```
<?php
namespace Miller\Utils;
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'Cookie.class.php';

ob_start();

$cookie = new Cookie('example_cookie', Cookie::SESSION);
var_dump($cookie->exists());
   // true if cookie is stored in the browser already, false otherwise
var_dump(isset($cookie->example_prop));
   // true if example_prop exists in cookie, false otherwise
var_dump($cookie->example_prop);
   // the value of example_prop, or null if it is not set
$cookie->example_prop = 123;
var_dump($cookie->example_prop);
   // will still be the previous value, because the cookie hasn't been sent
var_dump($cookie->example_prop_2);
   // the value of example_prop_2, or null if it is not set
unset($cookie->example_prop_2);
var_dump($cookie->example_prop_2);
   // will still be previous value, because cookie hasn't been sent
$cookie->current_time = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'));
   // will serialize objects using PHP native function and unserialize automatically
var_dump($cookie->send());
   // -1, -2, or 0 (ERROR_HEADERS_SENT, ERROR_SET_COOKIE, or ERROR_NONE)
var_dump($cookie->example_prop);
   // if send() was successful, this will now be 123
var_dump(isset($cookie->example_prop_2));
   // if send() was successful, this will now be false
var_dump($cookie->current_time);
   // if send() was successful, this will now be the recorded time

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the closing `?>` in definition files (PHP recommends not using the closing tag!). If a file is called `something.class.php`, I'd expect it to contain _only_ a class definition, not functions, too... Implement one of the `Travesable` interfaces, so you can use the _real_ `isset`, not your pseudo-magic `__isset` method

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I think your comment would be worth an answer (with some references). I'd upvote it.

Comment: @palacsint: Posted a rand/answer there's quite a lot more that needs doing in this code, come to think of it... sorry if I put things bluntly, but [You have to, when doing code-review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/810/guidelines-for-new-users-proposal-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I've posted a fairly length answer on the subject of request classes, which can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29469/critique-request-php-request-method-class/29485#29485). Because you state you're thinking of writing a `Session` class on top of this one, I'm posting a link to my answer here.
In that answer, I discuss what you should keep in mind when doing so. For example: using setters and getters, sanitize all request data etc...

Then, as I said in the comment, I noticed you're using the `?>` closing tag, which is optional. Omitting it, especially in those files that will be `include` or `require`-ed is considered *good practice*. It's, amoungst other things, to avoid excess whitespace. [Read more here](http://www.php.net/basic-syntax.instruction-separation)
Another part of *good practice* is to write the doc-blocks just *before* the method definition, not in the function body. As soon as you start using [the `ReflectionClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) (especially the `getDocBlock` method), you'll see the value of this. Even if you don't use it, other libs might (like `Doctrine` to name one, not unimportant example)

You're also defining a method called `__isset`. The double underscore would suggest this is a magic-method, that enables the user of this class to write something like:

```
if (isset($instance['cookieName']))
```

And that php will convert that into `if ($instance->__isset('cookieName'))`. That's not the case. The magic `isset` method only works when you write `isset($instance->cookieName)`, which, to all intents and purpouses still is a different syntax.
If I were in your shoes, I'd implement a [`Travesable` interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), or [the `ArrayAccess` interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). read through the examples, and you'll see array-like usage of `isset` is possible thanks to this interface.

The last remark I'd like to make is the fact that your file is called `Cookie.class.php`, so I'd expect its contents to be *just* a class definition. It isn't, though: you're defining a function, too. That's just *not nice*. I'd suggest you read, and make sure to comply with the unofficial [PHP-FIG standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted). Though not official, all major players (check [list here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards)) subscribe to these standards. If your code complies, too, autoloaders from any of the major frameworks will *just work* with your classes.
While I'm on the subject of autoloaders: implement them, use them, rely on them. If your classes are defined according to the aforementioned standards, you can do away with all those pesky `require`'s. Even if you do need the occasional `require`: use the safer `require_once` variant. Sure it's a tad slower, but at least it's safe.

Oh, and if you *still* need that `array_copy` in the `Miller\Utils` namespace, you *could* use a static method, since PHP statics are just globals in drag, or declare a global function and call it with a leading `\`.
Still, look at *where* you're using it:

```
public function __construct ($name, $expiry = self::WEEK, $path = '', $domain = '', $secure = null, $httponly = false)
{
    $this->name = (string) $name;
    if ($expiry === self::SESSION) {
        $this->expiry = $expiry;
    }
    else if (is_numeric($expiry)) {
        $this->expiry = time()+$expiry;
    }
    else {
        $this->expiry = strtotime($expiry);
    }

    $this->path = (string) $path;
    $this->domain = (string) $domain;
    $this->secure = $secure === null ? isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] : (bool) $secure;
    $this->httponly = (bool) $httponly;

    $this->properties = array ();
    $this->internalProperties = array ();
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->name])) {
        $properties = unserialize($_COOKIE[$this->name]);
        $this->internalProperties = array_copy($properties);
        $this->properties = array_copy($properties);
    }
}
```

You're clearly using it to set properties inside the class, so why isn't this function *a private method*?

Moving on to some actual code review: Your constructor is doing *way* to much work. Besides, when I create a cookie, I'd like to be able to set the data *when I choose*, not passing it all to the constructor. I'd like to use a `Cookie` class to check if a given cookie exists, and if it does, check when it expires, if it doesn't I'd like to create it and *maybe* determine its expiration date/time later on. Implement setters and getters for that.
Also use these setters to sanitize whatever data is being passed to the constructor. Sure:

```
$this->name = (string) $name;
```

Assures you that the name property is bound to be a string. Good, but what if I passed an object. I'm not going to get an exception thrown, though I clearly passed an argument that is a good reason to throw an `InvalidArgumentException`. Don't just cast to the types you want, check if the arguments passed are:

1. Castable to the type without loss of data
2. Valid types in the first place

By the second I mean that, if I were to accidentally pass an instance of `PDO` as name, I should be notified of the error in *my* code. Basically: your class is too reliant on magic-methods, it allows *overloading of properties*, which is *terrible*, especially with *request objects* (the request shouldn't be subject to change, unless there's a good *method* defined for it). Some constants (like the `SESSION` constant indicate a class of responsability, check first link to find out more).
As ever: don't hush-up/work around errors. Throw exceptions when something is not quite right. You don't know why or how the name property was passed, and why it's not a string, nor does your class need to know. Just throw an exception. Let the user of your class fix his code.

On the use of `serialize`: Since you're thinking about a session object: if you're going to use `serialize`, save it for the session, just *don't use a cookie*.

On the `__set` method: check what the value is. If I'm setting something like:

```
$instance->connection = $pdo;
```

Your code won't complain, but you *can't serialize a DB connection*! In fact, there are quite a few things that can't be serialized. Google around a bit

Comment: What would you suggest in place of `serialize()` on unserializable objects? I think it would make more sense to include in the documentation that the `serialize()` function is called on properties and leave it up to the user to implement the `Serializable` interface, etc., because I can't accommodate an unlimited number of classes that are unserializable.

Comment: @MMiller: Personally, I'm not a big fan of `serialize` calls, especially when the serialized data ends up in a cookie or session, but that's just me. If you're keen on using it, though, I, too, would add it in the doc-block, and do something like `if (is_object($param) && !($param instanceof Serializable || $param instanceof stdClass)) throw new InvalidArgumentException('cannot be serialized safely');`